# Linq query sum up the amount column

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

```
var result = (from t1 in _dbEntities.Charges
              join t2 in _dbEntities.ChargesTypes on t1.ChargesTypeID equals t2.ID
              where t1.StudentID == 1033
              select new {t2.Amount}).SingleOrDefault();
```

I want to sum the `amount` column how to do that and it should be convert into `int` before sum it up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you're using `SingleOrDefault` which will only select a single value. You want to use `Sum` instead. Also, you don't need an anonymous type here. You can just use:

```
var result = (from t1 in _dbEntities.Charges
              join t2 in _dbEntities.ChargesTypes on t1.ChargesTypeID equals t2.ID
              where t1.StudentID == 1033
              select (int) t2.Ammount).Sum();
```

Alternatively, you could use the form of `Sum` which takes a projection, possibly using a different form of `Join` as you only want the `t2` value:

```
var result = _dbEntities.Charges
                        .Join(_dbEntities.ChargesTypes,
                              t1 => t1.ChargesTypeID,
                              t2 => t2.ID,
                              (t1, t2) => t2)
                        .Sum(t2 => (int) t2.Ammount);
```

Or even convert in the join and use the "plain" `Sum` afterwards:

```
var result = _dbEntities.Charges
                        .Join(_dbEntities.ChargesTypes,
                              t1 => t1.ChargesTypeID,
                              t2 => t2.ID,
                              (t1, t2) => (int) t2.Ammount)
                        .Sum();
```

EDIT: If the `Ammount` column (which should be `Amount` by the way) in the database is an `NVARCHAR` then a) change it if you possibly can. Life is always simpler if the database types are appropriate; b) use `int.Parse` if you can't:

```
var result = (from t1 in _dbEntities.Charges
              join t2 in _dbEntities.ChargesTypes on t1.ChargesTypeID equals t2.ID
              where t1.StudentID == 1033
              select int.Parse(t2.Ammount)).Sum();
```

If that doesn't work, you *may* need to do the parsing on the .NET side, e.g.

```
var result = (from t1 in _dbEntities.Charges
              join t2 in _dbEntities.ChargesTypes on t1.ChargesTypeID equals t2.ID
              where t1.StudentID == 1033
              select t2.Ammount)
             .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest client-side
             .Sum(x => int.Parse(x));
```

Comment: issues is that ammount column in db is a type of nvarchar so convert it to first int here how to do that

Comment: @Mike: How was I meant to guess that? You could try using `int.Parse` instead of the cast, or you could fetch all the strings and then sum afterwards. I'll add an edit - but please take more care to add all the relevant information to the question to start with in the future.

Comment: thanks Jon .. Im new to entity can you please guide me the site i want to learn it from basics of entity frame work  your reply will be appreciated

Comment: @Mike: I suggest you get a good book, or maybe watch a good Pluralsight course. There are *lots* of resources available, but I don't have much experience of EF myself, so don't have much in the way of recommendations. Julie Lerman has good Pluralsight courses, I believe.